# what happens if i delete a file while tar is processing it?

Tags: command-line, backup, tar, rm

I am attempting to backup my filesystem with the following command:

```
tar -cvjf /fs.bz2 --exclude=/fs.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

This command has been running, and outputing each file processed, and has progressed up to a certain 2 GB file named `20130601.tgz`. I've decided that I don't need to keep this file, and so while tar was processing it, I deleted this file with `rm`.

tar appears to still be processing the file as it has not outputed the next file to be processed, and the filesize of the bzip2 file continues to grow. previously, tar seems to recognise that a file had changed while it was edited and had said so, and continued on to the next file. I've also recreated the file with the following command: `echo hello > 20130601.tgz`

three related questions:

- why did it not recognise that it has been modified this time?
- do i need to start my tar command again?
- if it is still processing the same file even though I deleted it, where is it getting the contents of the file in order to process it?

EDIT: question number 1 and 2 are answered by the following output of my command:

```
tar: /srv/www/nachtkriecher.com/backups/20130601.tgz: file changed as we read it
```

Question 3 still remains though! What was it doing while I was waiting?

Comment: I have 2 GB RAM so I suppose it's possible it was holding the whole file in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what happens if i delete a file while tar is processing it?

Absolutely nothing.  Deleting a file just removes the name from the directory.  The file itself is still there as long as it has a name in another directory, or any process already has it open.  Since `tar` already had the file open, it continues to process it just fine.

Comment: so... it was still reading it from disk even though it appeared deleted? maybe i should have done `echo hello > 20130601.tgz` before deleting it, and then that would have actually changed the file contents on disk?

Comment: @Nacht, that is correct.  The echo created a brand new file that just happened to have the name the old one used to have.